# Can I EnterCriticalSection(s) in thread A then LeaveCriticalSection(s) in thread B?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

So i have SEND_SLOT struct:

```
struct SEND_SLOT
{
    SEND_BUFFER buffer;
    uint16 index;
    CRITICAL_SECTION slotLock;
};
```

and a connexion struct:

```
struct connexion
{
    ...
    SEND_SLOT sendSlots[3];
    ...
}
```

and in thread A i do:

```
if(TryEnterCriticalSection(&sendSlots[i]))
{  //Post send request...
   WSASend(...);
}
```

and in thread B i do:

```
while(...)
{
   ...
   //request finished, data sent, and i get the index to the SEND_SLOT
   LeaveCriticalSection(&sendSlots[index]);
   ...
}
```

So i'm trying to lock the SEND_SLOT i in thread A and later i want to unlock it, maybe from an other thread, but its not working, each time i try to post new send it locks the first slot even if it hash already been locked and no LeaveCriticalSection has been issued. WHY?

Comment: Its called , Windows IOCP :D

Comment: Seen something like this done in a another OS with a mutex the programmer was using as a conditional flag to prevent other threads from writing into a serial port while it was in use. The code worked. Until another programmer fixing another bug stumbled across what looked like an unreleased mutex and politely fixed it. Ooops. The thing is, programmer 1 violated the hell out of [the Law of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) by using the mutex way outside it's expected use. Even if you can pull a hack like this, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not legal.  The [documentation for `LeaveCriticalSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169(v=vs.85).aspx) explains that the same thread that called `EnterCriticalSection` must also call `LeaveCriticalSection`:

> A thread uses the `EnterCriticalSection` or `TryEnterCriticalSection` function to acquire ownership of a critical section object. To release its ownership, the thread must call `LeaveCriticalSection` once for each time that it entered the critical section.
>
> If a thread calls `LeaveCriticalSection` when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using `EnterCriticalSection` to wait indefinitely.

The same sort of restriction applies to a mutex. For your case, a semaphore would be more appropriate.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> only the thread that owns a mutex can successfully call the `ReleaseMutex` function, though any thread can use `ReleaseSemaphore` to increase the count of a semaphore object.

Comment: @BalanNarcis: Yes.  This association with a single thread is what allows the OS to detect an abandoned critical section.

Comment: So if i want to 'lock' certain element of list, and later to unlock it form an other thread, what should i use?

Comment: @BalanNarcis This question strikes at the heart of what the difference is between a _mutex_ and a _binary semaphore_. The former has a concept of _ownership_, the latter does not. A binary semaphore _can_ act as a mutex, but only if software arranges itself so that the thread that takes it is the only one to give it back. The knowledge that a mutex will only be unlocked by the currently-owning thread could be used to optimize the mutex unlock from an atomic read-modify-write to a store with release semantics, for instance.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: *ownership* is also rather important to enabling recursive acquisition.

Comment: @BenVoigt: although I gather there is a great deal of debate in some circles as to whether allowing recursive acquisition is a good thing or not. :-)